# Sort cookies with Javascript

Tags: javascript

When a cookie is created or modified, it is added at the end.

I have these cookies, with the name and age. When doing document.cookie it shows:

```
Client1=Mike#32; Clien2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23
```

On the screen I show in the order that they have been created.

> Mike 32 years old
>
> Peter 19 years old
>
> Mary 23 years old

My problem is when modifying, for example the first one (John), the last one is located:

```
Clien2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23; Client1=Mike#33;
```

and it shows:

> Peter 19 years old
>
> Mary 23 years old
>
> Mike 33 years old

How can I maintain the order of the principle when modifying a cookie?

Thank you very much.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: John? Have you maybe tried making an array from the cookies and sorting it by whatever you want?

Comment: John is Mike ?? isn't

Comment: Why store that information in cookies?

Comment: Is there any reason you need it in your cookie instead of in response/request body? Do you need all of them every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work based on your requirement (Sort based on Client1, Client2, Client3);

let me know whether this worked for you. Happy Coding :)

```js
// sorting based on the client1, client2, client3

let cookieData = "Client2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23; Client1=Mike#32;";

let arrofObj = [];
cookieData.split(";").filter(String).forEach(o => {
   var tempData = o.split("=")
   arrofObj.push({"key":tempData[0].trim(),"value":tempData[1]})
})

let sortedArr = arrofObj.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.key > b.key) ? 1 : ((b.key > a.key) ? -1 : 0);} ); 

console.log(sortedArr);

let values = sortedArr.map(o => o.value);

values.forEach(o => {
  let temp = o.split("#");
  console.log(`${temp[0]} is ${temp[1]} years old`)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have adapted it to my application and it works very well. Have a nice day.

Comment: if it worked just accept it as the answer :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can do it. when you check document.cookie you will get the cookie as a string.

// assuming your cookie data will be

```
 let cookieData =  "Client1=Mike#32; Clien2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23";
```

```js
let cookieData = "Client1=Mike#32; Clien2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23";

cookieData.split(";").forEach(o => {
  let current = o.split("=")[1].split("#"),
      currrentPersonName = current[0],
      currentPersonAge = current[1];
    console.log(`${currrentPersonName} ${currentPersonAge} years old`);
})

// when you modify it we can sort it and show below shows is ascending

console.log("when its modified....")

let cookieDataModified = "Clien2=Peter#19; Client3=Mary#23; Client1=Mike#32;";

let arrayToBeSorted = [];

cookieDataModified.split(";").forEach(o => {
  let current = o.split("=")[1]
      arrayToBeSorted.push(current)
})

arrayToBeSorted.sort().forEach(o => {
   let current = o.split("#");
   console.log(`${current[0]} ${current[1]} years old`)   
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try it.

Comment: here its a basic sort , you can sort in any way once if its works we can refactor the code to reduce the loops. happy coding :)

Comment: In your example, sort by name. Could you sort it by the name of the cookie? (Customer1, Customer2, Customer3 ..)

Thank you very much.

Comment: i have updated another answer based on your requirement. Please let me know whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody.

This is the code:

```
function CarritoMiniMues() {        
    var Cookies; // Cookies
    Cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

    StringTot = "";      
    StringTot = StringTot + '<table>'; 

    var ca = Cookies.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {        
        StringTot = StringTot + '<tr>'; // Open line            
        var c = ca[i];
        if (c != ''){
            // YES cookies              
            var ca2 = c.split('#');
            for(var i2 = 0; i2 < ca2.length; i2++) { 
                if (i2 == 0){ // NAME
                    StringTot = StringTot + '<td>' + ca2[i2] + '</td>';
                }
                if (i2 == 1){ // AGE
                    StringTot = StringTot + '<td>' + ca2[i2] + ' years old</td>';
                }                       
            }
        }else{
            // NO cookies
            StringTot = '<td colspan="6">empty</td>';
        }

        StringTot = StringTot + '</tr>'; // close line
    }   
    StringTot = StringTot + '<table>';       
    document.getElementById("resul").innerHTML = StringTot;  // Show results                   
}
```